# Travis unable to start mongodb instance

Tags: mongodb, travis-ci, setup-deployment

I am using Travis CI/CD in my repository. When my build starts on Travis. Getting below error:

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found.
```

Here is my travis.yml file config

```js
os: linux
dist: focal
group: edge
arch: arm64-graviton2
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "14"
before_install: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_AUTH_TOKEN" >> ./.npmrc
services:
  - mongodb
env:
  - MONGO_HOSTS=localhost:27017
script:
  - npm run-script lint
  - npm test
before_deploy: |
  pip install --user awscli
  curl -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" -O -L "https://mygihub/master/src/assume-role.sh"
deploy:
  edge: true
  provider: script
  script: bash scripts/deploy.sh
  on:
    branch:
      - master
      - uat
      - develop
```

What caused this issue, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

We are actually seeing the same - asked in Travis community - https://travis-ci.community/t/failed-to-start-mongodb-service/13373

Comment: appreciate your answer. but Travis... come on... seriously?